# Oracle SQL Paired Data

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, difference

I need to find the difference in averages between patient weights at different visits (time points), but I'm struggling with finding the "paired" averages:

I have 1 table (PHYS) containing patient weights at different visits:

```
PATIENT    VISIT       WEIGHT
1          Baseline    200
1          1 Month     190
1          2 Month     170
2          Baseline    300
2          1 Month     290
2          2 Month     280
3          Baseline    250
3          1 Month     230
```

My problem is that I only want to find the difference for paired data. For example, when calculating the amount of weight loss between the 2 month and Baseline visits, I would want to find the difference between the (average 2 Month weight) and the (average Baseline weight FOR ONLY THOSE PATIENTS WITH A 2 MONTH WEIGHT). In this example, the result should be AVG(170,280) - AVG(200,300) = -25 (since only patient 1 and 2 have 2 Month weights).

Here is what I have, but it calculates the difference based on all weights:

```
SELECT VISIT
  AVG(WEIGHT)
  -
(SELECT
  AVG(WEIGHT)
  FROM PHYS
  WHERE VISIT = 'BASELINE')
FROM PHYS
GROUP BY VISIT
```

My desired output would be (I know I need to add an `ORDER BY`):

```
VISIT      CHANGE FROM BASELINE
Baseline   0
1 Month    -13.3
2 Month    -25
```

Thank you and sorry for such a newb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `join` to the same table but only for the `'Baseline'`.  Then, the aggregation only aggregates the values that match, so you should get different baseline averages for the three groups (because the populations are different):

```
select p.visit, avg(p.weight) as avg_weight, avg(pbl.weight) as avg_blweight,
       (avg(p.weight) - avg(pbl.weight)) as change
from phys p join
     phys pbl
     on p.patient = pbl.patient and
        pbl.visit = 'Baseline'
group by p.visit;
```

Comment: This is really great, thanks! I didn't know I could join on the same table!